# chaining pre-transformations for a node-set (first sorting child nodes, then another transformation on the sorted result). Can my code be simplified?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm using xsl:copy to do a sequential series of (pre-)transformations. First, sorting of child elements, then a pre-transformation on the sorted result. (more pre-transformations could be chained afterwards).

The problem is that I'm also using node-set().
My solution works but uses an identity-transform for each pre-transformation, which seems wrong.

**The source**

```
<albums>
    <album title="hits of the 90s" status="ready">
        <tracks>
            <track id="01" year="1992" title="I'm Too Sexy" />
            <track id="02" year="1991" title="Baby Baby" />
            <track id="03" year="1990" title="It Must Have Been Love" />
            <track id="04" year="1994" title="Here Comes the Hotstepper" />
            <track id="05" year="1998" title="Gettin' Jiggy Wit It" />
            <track id="06" year="1993" title="Dreamlover" />
            <track id="07" year="1996" title="Macarena"/>
            <track id="08" year="1995" title="Gangsta's Paradise" />
            <track id="09" year="1996" title="Un-Break My Heart" />
            <track id="10" year="1997" title="Wannabe" />
            <track id="11" year="1999" title="Baby One More Time" />
            <track id="12" year="1998" title="My Heart Will Go On"/>
        </tracks>
    </album>
</albums>
```

**The output**

```
<album title="hits of the 90s" status="ready">
    <tracks>
        <sideA>
            <track id="03" year="1990" title="It Must Have Been Love"/>
            <track id="02" year="1991" title="Baby Baby"/>
            <track id="01" year="1992" title="I'm Too Sexy"/>
            <track id="06" year="1993" title="Dreamlover"/>
            <track id="04" year="1994" title="Here Comes the Hotstepper"/>
            <track id="08" year="1995" title="Gangsta's Paradise"/>
        </sideA>
        <sideB>
            <track id="07" year="1996" title="Macarena"/>
            <track id="09" year="1996" title="Un-Break My Heart"/>
            <track id="10" year="1997" title="Wannabe"/>
            <track id="05" year="1998" title="Gettin' Jiggy Wit It"/>
            <track id="12" year="1998" title="My Heart Will Go On"/>
            <track id="11" year="1999" title="Baby One More Time"/>
        </sideB>
    </tracks>
</album>
```

**The code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" extension-element-prefixes="exsl msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vAlbums">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="albums/album[@status = 'ready']" mode="chained_subtransformations">
                <xsl:sort select="@title" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($vAlbums)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="album" mode="chained_subtransformations">
        <xsl:if test="tracks/track">
            <!-- sort the tracks -->
            <xsl:variable name="album_with_sorted_tracks">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sorttracks"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- split the album in half -->
            <xsl:variable name="splitAlbum">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($album_with_sorted_tracks)" mode="split"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- the following line could be replaced with the apply-templates of the previous subtransformation -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($splitAlbum)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- SORTING THE TRACKS -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="sorttracks">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="sorttracks"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tracks" mode="sorttracks">
        <tracks>
            <xsl:for-each select="track">
                <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tracks>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- SPLITTING THE ALBUM -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="split">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="split"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tracks" mode="split">
        <xsl:variable name="halfOfTotalTracks" select="floor(count(track) div 2)"/>
        <tracks>
            <sideA>
                <xsl:for-each select="track[position() &lt;= $halfOfTotalTracks]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sideA>
            <sideB>
                <xsl:for-each select="track[position() &gt; $halfOfTotalTracks]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sideB>
        </tracks>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xslt1.0, processor: MSXML3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "pre-transformation" and esp. by this:

> more pre-transformations could be chained afterwards

AFAICT, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/albums">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="album[@status = 'ready']">
        <xsl:sort select="@title" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="album">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="track-count" select="count(tracks/track)" />
        <xsl:if test="$track-count">
            <xsl:variable name="sorted-tracks-RTF">
                <xsl:for-each select="tracks/track">
                    <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="sorted-tracks" select="msxsl:node-set($sorted-tracks-RTF)/track"/>
            <tracks>
                <sideA>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted-tracks[position() &lt;= $track-count div 2]"/>
                </sideA>
                <sideB>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted-tracks[position() > $track-count div 2]"/>
                </sideB>            
            </tracks>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This structure allows you add more templates to further transform any node before sending it to the output. In the absence of such overriding template, all nodes are handled by the *identity transform* template that copies them *as is*.

If you do not need additional processing, then you could simply copy the nodes directly to the output and get rid of the *identity transform* template.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly what you inferred: "to add more templates to further transform any node before sending it to the output". Thanks, your solution is amazing. I was way off.

Comment: I also tried your alternative, i.e. to replace the apply-templates, in the match-album template, by copy-of (and removing the id  transform) and that worked great as well!

Comment: I didn't know you could put a variable  (sorted-tracks-rtf) inside an <xsl:if>...

Comment: You can a put a variable anywhere you want - just keep in mind that its scope is limited to its following siblings and their descendants,

Comment: Say I wanted to cut and paste the code to build the <tracks> node in a separate template. Would that be possible in the current structure? How would I pass $sorted-tracks to this other template?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. `tracks` is the parent of `track` - why would you need to pass the sorted children back to the parent?

Comment: I meant, if I had a separate template to replace the tracks node.  (I suppose the sorting would have to be inside this template. or can you pass the variable?) <xsl:template match="tracks">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted-tracks"/>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: The sorting would be best done in the template matching `tracks`. And you would need a template to copy the `album` element - either the identity transform template or a dedicated template matching `album`. But since the `tracks` element is just a wrapper, I don't see what a template  matching it would do that couldn't be done in the template matching its parent `album`.